# Inspecting digital signature in PDF file

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader, digital-signature, smartcard

I have a PDF that was signed with a certificate from a PKCS#11 module (a Belgian identity card reader, also known as eID) using Adobe Acrobat Reader DC. How can I inspect the signature that's attached to the document?

Basically, I'm interested in seeing the same type of information you can also get from your browser when inspecting an SSL certificate:

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How can I inspect the signature that's attached to the document?

> 1. Open the PDF containing the signature.
> 2. Open the Signatures panel, and select the signature.
> 3. On the Options menu, click Show Signature Properties, and then click Show Signer’s Certificate.
> 4. If the certificate is self-signed, contact the originator of the certificate to confirm that the fingerprint values on the Details tab
>      are correct. Trust the certificate only if the values match the values
>      of the originator.

Source [Securing PDFs with certificates](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/securing-pdfs-certificates.html)

Comment: I haven't found a Signatures panel in Adobe Reader DC yet. Where is it?

Comment: Oh, found it. It's underneath the toolbar if the document contains a signature. Turns out my test document was signed incorrectly. Nevermind!

Comment: Obviously this answer is only valid for Adobe PDF software on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

In case you are looking for a solution using FOSS and / or Linux / Mac, in theory there is a tool called pdfsig which comes with more recent versions of the [Poppler library](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/poppler/). This is the underlying PDF engine for many FOSS PDF readers including evince, Okular, ePDFView, LocoPDF, GIMP, qAllInOne and qpdfview.

In practice your milage may vary. It seems that not all kinds of electronic signatures are supported yet, so you receive a warning message saying

```
Unimplemented Feature (0): Unable to validate this type of signature
```

Very recently a switch

```
-dump
```

has been introduced to pdfsig which allows you to extract the signature from the PDF so you can further evaluate it using other tools. This may also proof very useful for scripting.

Please also note that most PDF reader desktop applications which are based on the Poppler library are not yet picking up the PDF digital signature features in their UI.